# AppHarbor unnecessary single quotes for Entity Framework metadata in Connection string

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, appharbor

App Harbor generated this connection string :

```
metadata='res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient';
```

Required string:

```
metadata=res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How you passed `connectionString` ? you want remove `'` ?

Comment: Yes aria, I want to remove the single quote.

Comment: what code have you tried to get what you want to achieve ?

Comment: AppHarbor asks for Entity Framework metadata which I copied from my connection string: res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient; and when a final connection string is shown this value is enclosed in single quotes but I want this as it is.

Comment: So remove `'` by `Replace` of `string` .